# ssh one shot command gives partial results

Tags: ssh

I execute a command to grep a long log file on a remote server and the problem is whenever I ssh first and then execute the grep command remotely I get way more matches than if I do it in one shot as follows:

`ssh host 'less file | grep something'`

I was suspecting some default automatic timeout with the second version so I experimented with those options `-o ServerAliveInterval=<seconds> -o ServerAliveCountMax=<int>` but to no avail. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Try just `grep 'something' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to `less`. It does not behave well outside of interactive mode. Using `cat` solved the issue.